# Azure functions - Inbuilt web hook on fail over

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am working on azure functions, I need to trigger a web hook if it is failed. Is any inbuilt option available.

Also is any option for global error trigger for azure functions some thing we have in web job functions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that option does not currently exist out of the box. If you could open an issue with a feature request [here](https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues) describing your scenario, that would be great.

The error trigger is not currently exposed in Azure Functions. We do have an issue tracking that and other host level events [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/281).